# Pure function with pattern test

Tags: pure-function

Is it possible to achieve pattern test inside a pure function?
I have tried

```
f = Function[{x_?NumericQ},
    x
]
```

but the error Function::flpar occured.

Comment: No, this is not possible. `f = Replace[x_?NumericQ :> x^2]` is the closest thing you get.

Comment: Welcome to the community. You can achieve a similar effect with `If[MatchQ[x, _?NumericQ], ...]`, the only difference is when it doesn't match, you'll get an unevaluated expression normally but with `If` you can control what to return.

Comment: What is your larger objective? Without any other context, I'd say don't set f equal to a Function but instead give it DownValues. Is there a reason why you can't do that?

Answer (score 1):

You may do the pattern test inside the function and eventually return immediately without further evaluation. E.g.

```
f = (If[! NumericQ[#], "Argument not numeric", #^2]) &;

f[a]
Argument nnot numeric

f[2]
4
```